# Mapping specific index of dataframe with dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have dataframe and a dict:

```
d = {'col1': [11, 12, 13], 'col2': [14, 15, 16]}
dict_ = {'col1': '8', 'col2': '9'}
```

My dataframe has 3 indexes. These are 0, 1 and 2. I want to map last index values.
To put it simply my desire output is:

```
   col1  col2
0    11    14
1    12    15
2     8     9
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your right, you want to update last row with the `dict_` values:

```py
d = {"col1": [11, 12, 13], "col2": [14, 15, 16]}
dict_ = {"col1": "8", "col2": "9"}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.update(pd.DataFrame(dict_, index=df.index[-1:]))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 col2
0   11   14
1   12   15
2    8    9
```

Comment: Your solution is right, thank you. So how could I map not last but specific index in a dataset with many indexes?

Comment: @JuniorESE You can specify the `index=` of the `df` you want to change. In this example, I've specified last index `[-1:]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.iloc[-1, :] = dict_
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0   11    14
1   12    15
2    8     9
```

If there is some column in a dictionary which does exist in a dataframe, it will return NaN. It will also work if column will be put to the dictionary in a different order.